# как преобразовать дату с сервера в обычный вид т.е получить день или месяц? JQuery

Tags: jquery

сейчас у меня в  text() //2019-11-29 01:58:16

```js
cl.find('.post-data').find('.post-datetime').find('.month').text(data.posts[i].created_at);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var date = cl.find('.post-data').find('.post-datetime').find('.month').text(data.posts[i].created_at).split('-');
let year = date[0];
let month = date[1];
let day = date[2];
console.log(year)
console.log(month)
console.log(day)
```